# Flutter - SWIFT_VERSION must be set to a supported value

Tags: ios, flutter

Trying out the library simple_permission, fixed the pod error and this came up, no idea how to proceed. There's no setting for the swift version in Build Settings, I tried adding it, but it didn't work.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Skipping compilation. Fingerprint match.
Running Xcode clean...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET simple_permissions OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION             Debug ===
    The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

Answer (score 22):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060156/796963).

When the iOS part of a plugin is coded using Swift, you must make that change to your `ios/Podfile`. You must add `use_frameworks!` and `config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'`.

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!  # required by simple_permission
  ...
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'  # required by simple_permission
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

You might check which `SWIFT_VERSION` will be required, in [that issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16049), the problem is solved using 3.2. In the answer I posted, 4.1 was recommended but 4.0 also worked.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed by creating an empty swift file in the project.

Comment: this may sound crazy but it actually works (probably because it creates a bridging header)

Answer (score 4):

In the odd case that the other answers do not work for you, use `pre_install` like:

```
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.analysis_result.specifications.each do |s|
    s.swift_version = '4.2' unless s.swift_version
  end
end
```

A combination of the answers above and this answer will definitely sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16049

It helped me get past this for a project created without swift capability added and then adding on the geolocation plugin.

Answer (score 2):

> In this case bridging header must be created.
>
> 1. Open the project with XCode. Then choose File -> New -> File -> Swift File. A dialog will be displayed when creating the swift
>      file(Since this file is deleted, any name can be used.). XCode will
>      ask you if you wish to create Bridging Header, click yes. (It's a
>      major step)
> 2. Make sure you have use_frameworks! in the Runner block, in ios/Podfile.
> 3. Make sure you have SWIFT_VERSION 4.2 selected in you XCode -> Build Settings
> 4. Do flutter clean
> 5. Go to your ios folder, delete Podfile.lock and Pods folder and then execute pod install --repo-update

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the file ios/XX.podspec

```
s.swift_versions = ['4.0', '4.2', '5.0']
```

this will remove the error.