# Build error using Firebase and Geolocator (or any Swift plugin) in iOS (Flutter)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter

I'm trying to create a flutter app which use Firebase and the Geolocator plugin.

- The Firebase plugins I'll use to [authenticate](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth), use the [RTDB](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database) and [FCM](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging).
- The [Geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) is apparently a very reliable plugin for location awareness.

In Android, that's all fine - everything works great!

In iOS however, I cannot build the app, the error:

`The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.`

As I learned, using the Firebase plugins [requires you NOT to use_frameworks!](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9694#issuecomment-380772738) in the Podfile. And apparently, as Geolocator uses Swift code in the iOS part, [it requires you TO use_frameworks!](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16049#issuecomment-382629492) in the Podfile.

I know I could use another GPS plugin, such as [Location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location), however as it applies for any Swift code plugin, my question is:

**With Flutter, is it possible to use Firebase together with any Swift plugin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in this area but it looks like specifying the Swift version in your `Podfile` might solve the above mentioned error. You can do so by adding the following line:

`config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'`

It should be part of the `post_install` block, like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tested it previously, but only with '3.2'! It worked both with 4.0 and 4.1. Thank you very much!

Comment: That’s great to hear, glad I could help.