# Can't run my project after installed file_picker: ^4.6.1

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

**I installed [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker): ^4.6.1 and after I can't run my project. Without [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker): ^4.6.1 my project works well.**

**My debug console:**

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 mini in debug mode... Running pod
> install... CocoaPods' output: ↳
> Preparing
>
> ````
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Inspecting targets to integrate
>   Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
>
> Finding Podfile changes
>   A file_picker
>   - Flutter
>   - google_maps_flutter
>   - image_picker_ios
>   - open_file
>   - path_provider_ios
>
> Fetching external sources
> -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
> -> Fetching podspec for `file_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/file_picker/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `google_maps_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_ios/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `open_file` from `.symlinks/plugins/open_file/ios`
> -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
>
> Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
>   CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
>   CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
>
> ――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
>
> ### Command
>
> ```
> /usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose
> ```
>
> ### Report
>
> * What did you do?
>
> * What did you expect to happen?
>
> * What happened instead?
>
>
> ### Stack
>
> ```
>    CocoaPods : 1.11.3
>         Ruby : ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
>     RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
>         Host : macOS 12.4 (21F79)
>        Xcode : 13.4.1 (13F100)
>          Git : git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
> Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
> Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
> ```
>
> ### Plugins
>
> ```
> cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
> cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
> cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
> cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
> cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
> ```
>
> ### Podfile
>
> ```ruby
> # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
> # platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
> ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
>
> project 'Runner', {
>   'Debug' => :debug,
>   'Profile' => :release,
>   'Release' => :release,
> }
>
> def flutter_root
>   generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'),
> ````
>
> **FILE**)
> unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
> raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is
> executed first"
> end
>
> ````
>   File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
>     matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
>     return matches[1].strip if matches
>   end
>   raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
> end
>
> require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
>
> flutter_ios_podfile_setup
>
> target 'Runner' do
>   use_frameworks!
>   use_modular_headers!
>
>   flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
> end
>
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> ### Error
>
> ```
> LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle,
> ````
>
> 0x0009): tried:
> '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o
> file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64e')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in` <top (required)>'
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in` <top (required)>'
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in` download_and_save_with_retries_async'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in` download_file'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:284:in `ensure_versions_file_loaded' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208:in` search'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in
> `block in search' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in` select'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in
> `search' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in` create_set_from_sources'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in
> `find_cached_set' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in` specifications_for_dependency'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in
> `search_for' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in` block in sort_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in
> `each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in` sort_by'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in
> `sort_by!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in` sort_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in
> `block in sort_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in` with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in
> `sort_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in` push_state_for_requirements'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in
> `require_nested_dependencies_for' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in` activate_new_spec'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in
> `attempt_to_activate' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in` process_topmost_state'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in
> `resolve' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in` resolve'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in
> `resolve' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in
> `section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in` resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in` analyze'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in
> `block in resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in
> `resolve_dependencies' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in` install!'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in
> `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in` run'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in
> `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
> /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '
> ```
>
> ```
> ――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
>
> [!] Oh no, an error occurred.
>
> Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
> https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+tried%3A+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64e%27%29%29+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues
>
> If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
> https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new
>
> Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
> https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
>
> Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
>
> Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
> ```
>
> Error output from CocoaPods: ↳
> Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
>
> ```
> [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a
> ```
>
> platform for this target in your Podfile. See
> `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
>
> Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 13
> mini.

**flutter doctor:**

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm,
> locale en-GB)
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 32.1.0-rc1)
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
>
> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
>
> [✓] HTTP Host Availability
>
> • No issues found!

**COCOAPODS: 1.11.3**

**MacBook Air M1 MacOS Monterey Version 12.4 (21F79)**

**XCODE Version 13.4.1 (13F100)**

**Working with iPhone 13 mini**

Comment: read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912188/flutter-ios-build-fail-on-running-pod-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to ios folder of your project in terminal and run

```dart
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

If this fails
Run this commands in terminal

`arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`

Then inside the ios folder of your project run this command

`arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: Already tried to write this in the terminal and it did not help me. But right now in the new clean project everything worked. Huge thank you man